# How to enumerate a vector without knowing its element's type in reflection programming with C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, reflection

I'm trying to add dynamic reflection in C++ implementation with C++11.
Let's say, I have a base class named Object:

```
class Object {
public:
    Object() = default;
    ~Object() = default;
};
```

And two classes inherited from Object:

```
class Person : public Object {
public:
    std::string name;
    int age;
}

class Group : public Object {
public:
    std::string groupName;
    std::vector<Person> persons;
}
```

I've implemented RefectManager to record all the classes' meta information, and I create an object with a class name, for example:

```
Object *obj = RefectManager::CreateObject("Group");
MetaInfo *groupMeta = obj->GetMetaInfo();
```

where, "groupMeta" holds the meta information of class Group, it knows that:

> class Group has a field list with two fields inclued:
>   * one field named "groupName", and its **type's name** is "std::string"
>   * one field named "persons", and its **type's name** is "std::vector" and **the name** of the element's type in the vector is "Person"

I can get the Person's meta information through its name:

```
MetaInfo *personMeta = RefectManager::GetMetaInfo("Person");
```

But, is there a way to enumerate the field of "persons" in class Group with reflected meta informations dynamically, such as:

```
for (field in groupMeta's field list) {
    if (field type's name is "std::string") {
        get field's content as string
    } else if (field type's name is "std::vector") {
        // only the element type's name is known as "Person"

        // **how to enumerate the field with vector type?**

        // If we know the element's type through element type's name, 
        // we can do it as following:
        // std::vector<GetType<"Person">::type> *p = (std::vector<GetType<"Person">::type> *)field;
        // std::vector<GetType<"Person">::type>::iterator it = p->begin();
        // for (; it != p->end(); ++it) {
        //     //now we can access the element in field
        // }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, Quentin, I'm trying to format my question when you post a comment. Now it's done.

Comment: Are you stuck in C++11?  `std::any` in C++17 sort of solves many of your problems.  Second question, can you use `boost`?  Again, `boost::any` solves many of your problems.  Third question, do you know what type erasure is?  Forth question, is there a finite set of types you need to support?  Fifth question, what operations *exactly* do you need to perform on the `vector`?

Answer (score 0):

A `vector<int>` and a `vector<bool>` and a `vector<Person>` are unrelated types.

You are saying "they are all vectors, with different content", but in C++ templates produce *types*.  `std::vector` isn't a type, it is a factory of types.

We can still do something here.  We can talk about what operations a `vector` supports, and what we care about.

Suppose we only want to be able to read our `vector`s.  In fact, we only want to be able to iterate!

Start with the idea of having an `any_view`, where an `any_view` is a view of anything (like a `void*` but smarter).  Now a `vector<Foo>` is a kind-of `range<any_view>`.

This "view" concept splits values from references or pointers-to values.  Your `Object` type is suitable for a value, not for a view of a value.

Most of the stuff you can do to an `Object*` are the kind of operations you want on an `any_view`; but the `any_view` doesn't own what it is viewing unlike an `Object`.

The interface (ignoring details) looks something like this:

```
template<class It>
struct range_t{
  It b, e;
  It begin() const { return b; }
  It end() const { return e; }
  bool empty() const { return begin()==end(); }
  // etc
};
template<class X>
struct any_input_iterator{
  // implement a boost-like type erasure wrapper around
  // the concept of input iteration (read only single-pass iteration)
  using self=any_forward_iterator;
  friend bool operator==(self const&, self const&);
  friend bool operator!=(self const&, self const&);
  self& operator++();
  self operator++(int);
  X operator*()const;
  using value_type = std::remove_reference_t<X>;
  using reference = X;
  // etc
};
template<class X>
using iterable_over = range_t< any_input_iterator<X> >;

struct any_view {
  std::typeinfo const* get_typeid() const;
  template<class T>
  T* get_as() const;
  iteratable_over<any_view> members() const;
};
```

We then write traits classes that generates the back-end data that describes what an `any_view` of a type `T` looks like, and write converting constructors that take a `T&` and generates an `any_view`.  `any_view` holds a pointer to manual vtable of function pointers that implement the details, and a `void*` pointing at the `T&`, and dispatches its methods to it (passing in the `void*`).

This isn't easy, but it is a roadmap to a solution.  A full solution is a bit much for a single stack overflow post.

In particular, type erasing type erasure where we wrap `super_any` containing `std::ref`s for our `any_view`, and we type erase the operation of "get members", then we use an ADL free function or traits based method to describe the members and how to get them, would work.

After all this is done, your code might look like:

```
for (auto field : data) {
  if (*field.type_id() == typeid(std::string)) {
    std::string s = *field.get_as<std::string>();
  } else if (!field.members().empty()) {
    for (auto&& e:field.members()) {
      if (*e.second.type_id() == typeid(Person)) {
        Person& p = *e.get_as<Person>();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

note in this abstraction, a `vector` is just something with a pile of members, which are the elements.  Making it different can also be done.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Yakk, I have it done with lambda function to do type erasing.

When generating class member's meta info, I'll also generate a lambda function with it.

Thus, when doing enumerating a container, let the lambda function to do it, that's all.

Thanks Yakk again!